# NameError: name 'playerNumber' is not defined - even though i defined it in another function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Im coding a snake game for a project but for some reason it says that the variable playerNumber is not defined even though i very clearly defined it in the previous function. I dont really know whats wrong and i have tried various things and nothing has helped.

```
import turtle
gt = turtle.Turtle()
t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
t3 = turtle.Turtle()
t4 = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.bgcolor("White")

def start():
    print ("Welcome to python Snake! A game made by Kippo and inspired by the famous game: Snake!")
    playerNumber = int(input("How many players are going to play? (2-4)"))
    if playerNumber >= 5:
        print("Too many players! Try again.")
        start()
    elif playerNumber <= 1:
        print("Too few players! Try again.")
        start()
    else:
        playerColour()
        
def playerColour():
    global playerNumber
    if playerNumber == 1:
        player1colour = input("player 1, what colour do you want to be?")
    elif playerno == 2:
        player1colour = input("player 1, what colour do you want to be?")
        player2colour = input("player 2, what colour do you want to be?")
    elif playerno == 3:
        player1colour = input("player 1, what colour do you want to be?")
        player2colour = input("player 2, what colour do you want to be?")
        player3colour = input("player 3, what colour do you want to be?")
    elif playerno == 4:
        player1colour = input("player 1, what colour do you want to be?")
        player2colour = input("player 2, what colour do you want to be?")
        player3colour = input("player 3, what colour do you want to be?")
        player4colour = input("player 4, what colour do you want to be?")
    else:
        print ("Too many players, try again.")
        quit()
        
def gridSize():
    gridsize = int(input("What size do you want your grid to be?"))
    gt.circle(2)
    


start()
```

I have tried changing the name of the variable, moving the functions around, and trying various other methods of using the variable and nothing has changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python nonlocal statement / keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about scope.

You wrote this:

```
def start():
    playerNumber = ...

def playerColour():
    global playerNumber
    if playerNumber == ...
```

That is, start() makes an assignment,
and playerColor() hopes to read that value.
But as written, it's making an
assignment that is local to `start`.

Put a `global playerNumber` declaration within `start`,
and you will see different behavior.

---

## scope

Python maintains variable namespaces
at different levels of visibility,
including "top level" and "local to
a function" such as start() or
playerColour().

A *reference* to a name will probe
a few namespaces in sequence,
matching a function's local variables
before the top level global variables.

An *assignment* in a function will usually
create a local variable, which goes
out-of-scope (it is destroyed) upon
exiting the function.

A common "gotcha" in python looks like this:

```
name = "Alice"

def set_name():
    name = "Bob"

set_name()
print(name)
```

Question: what will this display?

Answer: Alice. Why? Because when we
set the name, we created a new local
variable. Which we then never used,
and it was destroyed when the function
exited.

To obtain the intended behavior,
declare a global:

```
def set_name():
    global name
    name = "Bob"
```

In practice, most code will prefer to
encapsulate such code and data
within a class, assigning to `self.name`
instead.
But that's a topic for another day.

---

## global variables

You are just starting out programming,
and I applaud that, go for it,
keep hacking.

I will just point out that once you've
written a couple of programs,
having debugged and maintained them,
you will start to see why most
folks view lots of global variables
as a problem-waiting-to-happen,
a source of coupling we try to design
out of our systems from the onset.

Python and other languages offer
features which seek to reduce
needless coupling, scoping variables
down so it's clear which bits of
code they affect.
Function arguments help to address
that need.
Defining a `class` can be a big
part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Friend mentioned the problem related to scope.You can fix the problem by doing what he said.

As a second way, you can give the playerNumber variable, where you store the value you get from the user, as a parameter to the function you use.
This will be a safer way to declare a global variable

```
def playerColour(playerNumber:int):
       // some logic


def start():
    print ("Welcome to python Snake! A game made by Kippo and inspired by the famous game: Snake!")
    playerNumber = int(input("How many players are going to play? (2-4)"))
    if playerNumber >= 5:
        print("Too many players! Try again.")
        start()
    elif playerNumber <= 1:
        print("Too few players! Try again.")
        start()
    else:
        playerColour(playerNumber)
```