# Keep getting an error that variable is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

So basically I have a tkinter app. I have three buttons: one shows the temperature, one shows humidity and one shows pressure. The thing that I am aiming for is that everytime one of the buttons is clicked is erases the current display (e.g. it is displaying temperature and I want to display humidity). I tried that with the function:

```
def clear_display():
    inside_temp_display.config(text="")
    outside_temp_display.config(text="")
    diff_temp_display.config(text="")
    inside_humid_display.config(text="")
    outside_humid_display.config(text="")
    diff_humid_display.config(text="")
    inside_press_display.config(text="")
    outside_press_display.config(text="")
    diff_press_display.config(text="")
```

but everytime I run the program I get the following error message:

> File "/home/pi/Documents/Meteo/meteo_tkinter.py", line 71, in clear_display
> inside_temp_display.config(text="")
> NameError: name 'inside_temp_display' is not defined

What am I doing wrong in the code?
P.S. I am using Tkinter and SenseHat Emulator. Here is the full code:

```
from sense_emu import SenseHat
from tkinter import *
import threading
import requests
import datetime as datetime

sense = SenseHat()

# ---- INSIDE TEMPERATURE, HUMIDTY AND PRESSURE ---- #
inside_temp = round(sense.get_temperature(), 2)
inside_humid = round(sense.get_humidity(), 2)
inside_press = round(sense.get_pressure(), 2)

# ---- OUTSIDE TEMPERATURE, HUMIDTY AND PRESSURE ---- #
url = 'https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=45.8144&longitude=15.978&hourly=temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,surface_pressure&timezone=Europe%2FBerlin&forecast_days=1'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

# ---- CALCULATE DIFFERENCES ---- #
outside_temp_hourly = data['hourly']['temperature_2m']
outside_humid_hourly = data['hourly']['relativehumidity_2m']
outside_press_hourly = data['hourly']['surface_pressure']

temp_diff = [round(temp - inside_temp, 2) for temp in outside_temp_hourly]
humid_diff = [round(hum - inside_humid, 2) for hum in outside_humid_hourly]
press_diff = [round(press - inside_press, 2) for press in outside_press_hourly]

# ---- GET CURRENT HOUR ---- #
now = datetime.datetime.now()
current_hour = now.hour


# ---- FUNCTIONS FOR THE BUTTONS ---- #
def show_current_temp():
    clear_display()
    inside_temp_display = Label(text = f"Current inside temperature: {inside_temp}°C.", pady=5)
    inside_temp_display.grid(row=2, column=1)
    
    outside_temp_display = Label(text = f"Current outside temperature: {outside_temp_hourly[current_hour]}°C.", pady=5)
    outside_temp_display.grid(row=3, column=1)
    
    diff_temp_display = Label(text = f"Difference in temperature is: {abs(temp_diff[current_hour])}°C.", pady=5)
    inside_temp_display.grid(row=4, column=1)
    

def show_current_humid():
    clear_display()
    inside_humid_display = Label(text = f"Current inside humidity: {inside_humid}%.", pady=5)
    inside_humid_display.grid(row=2, column=1)
    
    outside_humid_display = Label(text = f"Current outside humidity: {outside_humid_hourly[current_hour]}%.", pady=5)
    outside_humid_display.grid(row=3, column=1)
    
    diff_humid_display = Label(text = f"Difference in humidty is: {abs(humid_diff[current_hour])}%.", pady=5)
    inside_humid_display.grid(row=4, column=1)
    

def show_current_press():
    clear_display()
    inside_press_display = Label(text = f"Current inside pressure: {inside_press}hPa.", pady=5)
    inside_press_display.grid(row=2, column=1)
    
    outside_press_display = Label(text = f"Current outside pressure: {outside_press_hourly[current_hour]}hPa.", pady=5)
    outside_press_display.grid(row=3, column=1)
    
    diff_press_display = Label(text = f"Difference in pressure is: {abs(press_diff[current_hour])}hPa.", pady=5)
    inside_press_display.grid(row=4, column=1)


def clear_display():
    inside_temp_display.config(text="")
    outside_temp_display.config(text="")
    diff_temp_display.config(text="")
    inside_humid_display.config(text="")
    outside_humid_display.config(text="")
    diff_humid_display.config(text="")
    inside_press_display.config(text="")
    outside_press_display.config(text="")
    diff_press_display.config(text="")
    

# ---- MAIN GUI PROGRAM ---- #
def gui():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Weather")
    root.geometry("700x600")
    
    title = Label(root, text="Weather info", font=("Arial", 20), pady=20)
    title.grid(row=0, column=1)
    
    temp_button = Button(root, text="Display temperature", command = show_current_temp)
    temp_button.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=40)
    
    humid_button = Button(root, text="Display humidity", command = show_current_humid)
    humid_button.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=45, pady=20)
    
    press_button = Button(root, text="Display pressure", command = show_current_press)
    press_button.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=40)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

I tried a lot of combinations but non of them worked.

Comment: `inside_temp_display` is a local variable inside some other function.  It does not exist outside of that function.

Comment: It is a label inside show_curren_temp function.

Comment: @Frane it's a local variable that _only exists_ inside `show_curren_temp`, but you're trying to use it inside `clear_display`.

Comment: how do I make it global, sorry I am new to programming and Python?

Comment: Move this 

    inside_temp_display = Label(text = f"Current inside temperature: {inside_temp}°C.", pady=5)
    inside_temp_display.grid(row=2, column=1)

 outside of function.

Comment: Put this this before mainloop().

Answer (score 0):

As John Gordon mentioned, `inside_temp_display` is defined and thus only recognized inside the scope of `show_current_temp()`. You ca do

```
def f1():
    global x
    x = 1
    print(x, "in f1")
def f2():
    global x    
    print(x)
    x = 10
    print(x)
f1()
f2()
```

> 1 in f1
> 1
> 10

to let x be shared among different scopes, which is a more risky way when you project is complex.

Another way is passing your `inside_temp_display` to `show_current_temp()` as a parameter.

```
    def clear_display(inside_temp_display):
        inside_temp_display.config(text="")
```

Again another way is to do some OOP to let data member be shared, for example:

```
class GreatPlot:
    def __init__():
        self.inside_temp_display = None
    def show_current_temp():
        self.inside_temp_display = Label(text = f"Current inside temperature: {inside_temp}°C.", pady=5)
    def clear_display():
        self.inside_temp_display.config(text="")
my_great_plot = GreatPlot()
my_great_plot.show_current_temp()
my_great_plot.clear_display()
```

For `global` and `nonlocal`, see ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1261961/8329196

Comment: Are you sure the OOP example is correct?

Comment: I will try on of these options and let you know if it works. Thank you.

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria I edited a little bit to make the code formal. Thanks. Feel free to suggest to improve that!